# React useEffect() hook not working with JSON.parse,JSON.stringify

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have looked at xy answers to this problem, not a single one helped. I'm creating a simple react app for writing notes for myself. After writing a note I want it to be saved even after refreshing the page. For this I wanted to use `useEffect` hook, but it doesn't do it and yes its imported from react in header, thank you for any suggestions!

```
useEffect(() =>{
    const savedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("react-notes-app-data"));

    if(savedNotes) {
        setNotes(savedNotes);
    }
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("react-notes-app-data", JSON.stringify(notes));

}, [notes]);
```

I tried useEffect with JSON.parse and JSON.stringify to retrieve data (my note) when refreshing page.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with that: (as notes update it sets the thing)

```
function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("react-notes-app-data"));

    if (savedNotes) {
      setNotes(savedNotes);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("react-notes-app-data", JSON.stringify(notes));
  }, [notes]);

  const increase = () => {
    setNotes(['dwd', 'dwd', 'dwd'])
  }
  return (
    <div>
      123
      {notes && notes.map((el) => <div> {el} </div>)}
      <button onClick={increase}>123</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the problem was that I didn´t included if statement, like it was mentioned in comment bellow, that solved this problem, but thanks again for the effort! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `notes` is an array. You should check if there are any items in the array. The `useEffect` is run when the components render, at that moment the state of `notes` is still the initial, any empty array. So the localStorage will setItem with the empty array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (notes.length < 1) return;
  localStorage.setItem("react-notes-app-data", JSON.stringify(notes));
}, [notes]);
```